# Generating MERGE INTO in incremental model DBT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt

I would like to generate this kind of query in DBT using incremental model to merge data in BigQuery:

```sql
MERGE INTO `agency_workers` B_DEST
    USING `aktion_dc` SRC
    ON B_DEST.DATE = SRC.DATE
        AND B_DEST.WORKER = SRC.NAME|| ' ' || SRC.SURNAME
    WHEN MATCHED AND B_DEST.TIME_IN IS NULL THEN UPDATE
        SET B_DEST.SHIFT_NAME = SRC.SHIFT_NAME
            , B_DEST.AGENCY = SRC.AGENCY
            , B_DEST.ORGANIZATION_UNIT = SRC.ORGANIZATION_UNIT
            , B_DEST.TIME_IN = SRC.TIME_IN
            , B_DEST.TIME_OUT = SRC.TIME_OUT
            , B_DEST.WORKED = SRC.WORKED
```

My `agency_workers` destination dataset looks like that:

```sql
{{ config(
    materialized='incremental',
    unique_key=['DATE', 'WORKER']
) }}

SELECT
  S.DATE,
  S.SHIFT,
  S.SHIFT_FROM,
  S.SHIFT_TO,
  S.WORKER,
  S.LOGIN,
  S.JOB,
  W.SHIFT_NAME,
  S.NOTE,
  W.AGENCY,
  UPPER(S.AGENCY) AS AGENCY_SHORT,
  S.WORKER_SURNAME,
  S.WORKER_NAME,
  S.HOUR_WORK_SHIFTS,
  W.ORGANIZATION_UNIT,
  W.TIME_IN,
  W.TIME_OUT,
  W.WORKED,
  W.BREAKS,
  CASE
    WHEN S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('6:30:00' AS TIME)
         OR S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('6:00:00' AS TIME) THEN 'day'
    WHEN S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('18:30:00' AS TIME)
         OR S.SHIFT_FROM = CAST('18:00:00' AS TIME) THEN 'night'
  END AS SHIFT_TERM
FROM
  {{ ref('shifts') }} AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN {{ ref('aktion_dc') }} AS W ON S.WORKER_NAME = W.NAME
  AND S.WORKER_SURNAME = W.SURNAME
  AND S.DATE = W.DATE
```

However, using this config it is generating something completely different, which doesn't work. How can I create query like on top using DBT and incremental config?